# How to create path following contour

Tags: image-processing

I have an image (black & white) that represents a letter in the alphabet, and I want to create a path (x y coordinates) to represent the letter.

For example, I have this image of the letter C
([image of the letter C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOcZq.png))

I want to trace the white pixels, and obtain the positions for the path
[path position image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35qbx.jpg)

Comment: Is there any additional information - Printed? A fixed set?

Comment: I only have the image itself to calculate the points coordinates.

Comment: Do you have any prior data about what appears in the Image? What assumptions may be used - such as width of the curve? Only the 27 Characters? Numbers as well?...

Comment: Yes, only the 27 characters, but could be in different fonts. We can assume that the letter is always cropped & centered in the image, and we also know what character is inside the image.